# Software for creating beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, lyx, presentations

Lyx provide a simple GUI to create LaTeX presentations. But has lot of limitations. Ultimately you end up using LaTeX mark up. Is there a better program to create LaTeX presentation similar to LyX?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good place to ask since most people here would simple use - and prefer to use - an editor rather than dealing with LyX anyway. I don't mean it is off-topic - clearly not. But the audience here are unlikely to be pursuing this kind of possibility with particular ardour. The only GUI-ish solutions I'm aware of are LyX, the online options and then things like Scientific Word or whatever. For papers, it is different, but for presentations, why don't you just use one of the GUI programmes for slides? Why LaTeX?

Comment: Why not use LaTeX directly (i.e. why do you want a GUI?). On a separate note, if you have specific ideas for improving LyX, please help by posting them at http://www.lyx.org/trac . I use LyX + beamer frequently and although I certainly recognize it's not for everyone, I have not experienced any limitations.

Comment: I agree with the above comments, but seem that [BaKoma](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/menu/about.php) (commercial)  is what you are looking for.

Comment: Overlays play an important part in beamer. Lyx fails to provide effective support for overlays. Is their any good guide to beamer on lyx. I use texwork as a routine, but lyx file appear cleaner than tex and help focus more on work in hand rather than commands:)

Comment: @Sebastiano I don't think there is any need to edit old(-ish) posts for details such as this -- had this been a suggested edit I would have rejected it. If there are other larger concerns (e.g. retagging, fixing hopeless code markup, fixing links) then you could have done edits like that *in addition*, but please don't edit old posts just for insignificant details such as capitalization. See also http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-and-isnt-it-acceptable-to-edit

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Dear, I'm sorry if I did but as soon as I saw it picked me instinctively do.